# I have a base64 encoded png, how do I write the image to a file in PHP?

Tags: php, png, gd

What's the proper way in PHP to create an image file (PNG), when I have the base64 encoding?

I've been playing around with:

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/'. $_REQUEST['id'].'.png', $_REQUEST['data']);
```

do I need to decode? should I be using the gd library?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

My best guess is that you simply need to call `base64_decode()` on `$_REQUEST['data']` before writing it to the file. That should be plenty enough :).

Comment: sigh, that was easy enough, should have done that before asking the question! thanks.

Answer (score 64):

You need to use base64_decode(). AND. Sometimes it is not sufficient. Here is all code that you need:

```
$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
//saving
$fileName = 'photo.png';
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
```

P.S. I used this code to get PNG image from html canvas.

Comment: Is it possible to validate this image data? like normally you will validate all sorts of things before uploading the image

Answer (score 6):

I would think you'd want to decode with [base64_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) unless you are only using it like they are here [HERE](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64).

The thing I am sure of is that you will want to sanitize $_REQUEST['id'] before using it.