# Javascript webcam capture and upload to server with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, canvas

i have one page with a success image upload form canvas using a javascript and PHP upload file. the second page has a successful webcam capture to canvas and displays correctly. i am trying to adapt the image upload script with the cam capture the live css object does nothing...
the html is:
    
        
        snap

```
    <div id="upContent">
    <div class="upload-wrapper">
      <span id="upCanvas">Upload This Canvas</span>
    </div>
    <div class="return-data"></div>
</div>  

    <script src="js/interactioncam.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--script src="js/holder.js"></script-->
```

and the java script is:

```
//interactioncam.js - grab a pic
(function() {

  var data;
  var dataURL;

  var streaming = false,
      video        = document.querySelector('#video'),
      cover        = document.querySelector('#cover'),
      canvas       = document.querySelector('#canvas'),
      photo        = document.querySelector('#photo'),
      startbutton  = document.querySelector('#startbutton'),
      width = 320,
      height = 240;

  navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia || 
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia);

  navigator.getMedia(
    { 
      video: true, 
      audio: false 
    },
    function(stream) {
      if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { 
        video.mozSrcObject = stream;
      } else {
        var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        video.src = vendorURL ? vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
      }
      video.play();
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("An error occured! " + err);
    }
  );

  video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){
    if (!streaming) {
      height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth/width);
      video.setAttribute('width', width);
      video.setAttribute('height', height);
      canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
      streaming = true;
    }
  }, false);

  function takepicture() {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
  };

  startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
      takepicture();
    ev.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  // Convert DataURL to Blob object
  function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
    // Decode the dataURL
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();    
    var binary = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);
    // Create 8-bit unsigned array
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    // Return our Blob object
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
  }

  // Send IT
  $("#upCanvas").live("click", function(){
    $("#upCanvas").html("<img src='img/load.gif' alt='load'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Uploading ..");
    // Convert Canvas DataURL
    var dataURL= canvas.toDataURL();

    // Get Our File
    var file= dataURLtoBlob(dataURL);

    // Create new form data
    var fd = new FormData();

    // Append our image
    fd.append("imageNameHere", file);

    $.ajax({
       url: "uploadFile.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: fd,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
    }).done(function(respond){
      $("#upCanvas").html("Upload This Canvas");
        $(".return-data").html("Uploaded Canvas image link: <a href="+respond+">"+respond+"</a>").hide().fadeIn("fast");
    });
  });

})();
```

the php upload is:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upimg/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

any suggestions as to why i cannot get the canvas converted to a file and the upload script to work?

Answer (score 2):

You need  to **post** the captured image to `php`, for that you can use `jquery` `.ajax()`, here's a complete example:

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$img = !empty($_REQUEST['imgBase64']) ? $_REQUEST['imgBase64'] : die("No image was posted");
$imgName = $_REQUEST['imgName'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
//saving
file_put_contents($imgName, $fileData);
```

Now the `js`/`jquery`, `css` and `html`:

```js
(function() {
    // The width and height of the captured photo. We will set the
    // width to the value defined here, but the height will be
    // calculated based on the aspect ratio of the input stream.

    var width = 320; // We will scale the photo width to this
    var height = 0; // This will be computed based on the input stream

    // |streaming| indicates whether or not we're currently streaming
    // video from the camera. Obviously, we start at false.

    var streaming = false;

    // The various HTML elements we need to configure or control. These
    // will be set by the startup() function.

    var video = null;
    var canvas = null;
    var photo = null;
    var startbutton = null;

    function startup() {
        video = document.getElementById('video');
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        photo = document.getElementById('photo');
        startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');

        navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia);

        navigator.getMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: false
            },
            function(stream) {
                if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                    video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                } else {
                    var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                }
                video.play();
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log("An error occured! " + err);
            }
        );

        video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev) {
            if (!streaming) {
                height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);

                // Firefox currently has a bug where the height can't be read from
                // the video, so we will make assumptions if this happens.

                if (isNaN(height)) {
                    height = width / (4 / 3);
                }

                video.setAttribute('width', width);
                video.setAttribute('height', height);
                canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
                canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
                streaming = true;
            }
        }, false);

        startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            takepicture();
            ev.preventDefault();
        }, false);

        clearphoto();
    }

    // Fill the photo with an indication that none has been
    // captured.

    function clearphoto() {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        photo.setAttribute('src', data);
    }

    // Capture a photo by fetching the current contents of the video
    // and drawing it into a canvas, then converting that to a PNG
    // format data URL. By drawing it on an offscreen canvas and then
    // drawing that to the screen, we can change its size and/or apply
    // other changes before drawing it.

    function takepicture() {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (width && height) {
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            photo.setAttribute('src', data);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "upload.php",
                data: {
                    imgBase64: data,
                    imgName: "webcam.png"
                }
            }).done(function(o) {
                console.log('saved');
            });
        } else {
            clearphoto();
        }
    }

    // Set up our event listener to run the startup process
    // once loading is complete.
    window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);
})();
```

```css
#video {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
  width:320px;
  height:240px;
}

#photo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
  width:320px;
  height:240px;
}

#canvas {
  display:none;
}

.camera {
  width: 340px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.output {
  width: 340px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#startbutton {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  bottom:32px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
}

.contentarea {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
  width: 760px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contentarea">
  <div class="camera">
    <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
    <button id="startbutton">Take photo</button> 
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas">
  </canvas>
  <div class="output">
    <img id="photo" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box."> 
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Based on :**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13198699/797495
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31128229/797495

---

**Note:**
I've tested the code on my server and it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The FILES Upload name is `imageNameHere` not `file`.
To access the data you should replace imageNameHere with `file` or change the php code.
Otherwise the dataUrl on uploading may not in base64?

Answer (score 0):

You can add :

```
.canvas{display:block;}
```