# Send a blob with ajax, don't work in my case

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, blob

So, i have an image on my page with this for src attribut :

```
src="blob:47d2cdd6-0ff0-401f-a195-a671d0db9b05"
```

I need to send this blob to php with ajax, for save this blob (a gif in my case) on my server.

This is my ajax :

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', $('myImage').attr('src'));

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/webcam/",
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function () {
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
        },
        error: function() {
      alert("not so boa!");
    }
    });
```

But, when i am on my php script, i don't know how to use this blob... When i try `readimageblob()` from imagick for example, i have an error.

Am i in the good way ?

Comment: Why not just send it as a multipart form, as though doing a file upload?

Comment: To save that blob as an image on server side, you would do it as a normal upload in php, with : **$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']**

Comment: on my ph script, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] is null

Comment: Look at the html in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5587986/67566

Comment: Something like : $('myInputFile').val($('myImage').src) ? And after a submit of this form ?

Comment: What about **$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0]** ?

Comment: Okay, try to change the variable on data.append like this : **data.append($('input[name=image]').val());**

Comment: my blob value is not in an input, it's an image

Comment: You should do it with an input, it works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, but can i change with javascript the value of an input file ?

Comment: No, but why would want to change it ?

Comment: Because the blob data is created from a webcam, not from an input....

Comment: Hmmm, then I can't help you more, sorry, never tried with a webcam.

Comment: Then you should look at this, on how to upload from the webcam to php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152926/javascript-webcam-capture-and-upload-to-server-with-php