# webcam photo saving to hard disk using php script is not working

Tags: javascript, php

This code is not working to save the photo on hard disk, so  can anybody please tell me which code will used to save a photo to hard disk.

```
<html>
<head>
    <div id="my_camera" style="width:520px; height:440px;margin-left:180px;"></div>
    <div id="my_result" style="position:absolute;margin-left:740px;margin-top:-440px;"></div>
    <script src="cam/webcam.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
        function take_snapshot() {
            Webcam.set({
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                dest_width: 640,
                dest_height: 480,
                image_format: 'jpg',
                jpeg_quality: 90,
                force_flash: false,
                flip_horiz: true,
                fps: 45
            });

            Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
                document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
            });
        }
    </script>
    <a href="javascript:void(take_snapshot())" style="margin-left:400px">Take Snapshot</a>
</head>

</html>
<?php
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'], 'webcam.jpg');    
?>
```

Comment: You need to send the image to php, but I don't see any request to do that on your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  to **post** the captured image to `php`, for that you can use `jquery` `.ajax()`, here's a complete example:

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$img = !empty($_REQUEST['imgBase64']) ? $_REQUEST['imgBase64'] : die("No image was posted");
$imgName = $_REQUEST['imgName'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
//saving
file_put_contents($imgName, $fileData);
```

Now the `js`/`jquery`, `css` and `html`:

```js
(function() {
    // The width and height of the captured photo. We will set the
    // width to the value defined here, but the height will be
    // calculated based on the aspect ratio of the input stream.

    var width = 320; // We will scale the photo width to this
    var height = 0; // This will be computed based on the input stream

    // |streaming| indicates whether or not we're currently streaming
    // video from the camera. Obviously, we start at false.

    var streaming = false;

    // The various HTML elements we need to configure or control. These
    // will be set by the startup() function.

    var video = null;
    var canvas = null;
    var photo = null;
    var startbutton = null;

    function startup() {
        video = document.getElementById('video');
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        photo = document.getElementById('photo');
        startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');

        navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia);

        navigator.getMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: false
            },
            function(stream) {
                if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                    video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                } else {
                    var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                }
                video.play();
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log("An error occured! " + err);
            }
        );

        video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev) {
            if (!streaming) {
                height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);

                // Firefox currently has a bug where the height can't be read from
                // the video, so we will make assumptions if this happens.

                if (isNaN(height)) {
                    height = width / (4 / 3);
                }

                video.setAttribute('width', width);
                video.setAttribute('height', height);
                canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
                canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
                streaming = true;
            }
        }, false);

        startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            takepicture();
            ev.preventDefault();
        }, false);

        clearphoto();
    }

    // Fill the photo with an indication that none has been
    // captured.

    function clearphoto() {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        photo.setAttribute('src', data);
    }

    // Capture a photo by fetching the current contents of the video
    // and drawing it into a canvas, then converting that to a PNG
    // format data URL. By drawing it on an offscreen canvas and then
    // drawing that to the screen, we can change its size and/or apply
    // other changes before drawing it.

    function takepicture() {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (width && height) {
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            photo.setAttribute('src', data);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "upload.php",
                data: {
                    imgBase64: data,
                    imgName: "webcam.png"
                }
            }).done(function(o) {
                console.log('saved');
            });
        } else {
            clearphoto();
        }
    }

    // Set up our event listener to run the startup process
    // once loading is complete.
    window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);
})();
```

```css
#video {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
  width:320px;
  height:240px;
}

#photo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
  width:320px;
  height:240px;
}

#canvas {
  display:none;
}

.camera {
  width: 340px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.output {
  width: 340px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#startbutton {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  bottom:32px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
}

.contentarea {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
  width: 760px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contentarea">
  <div class="camera">
    <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
    <button id="startbutton">Take photo</button> 
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas">
  </canvas>
  <div class="output">
    <img id="photo" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box."> 
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Based on :**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13198699/797495
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31128229/797495

---

**Note:**
I've tested the code on my server and it works as intended.

Comment: I know its too late in the day. But this code show the error 'An error occured! SecurityError: Invalid security origin'

Comment: Are you accessing on a file:/// URL?